# Javascript Reg Exp Not Matching Correctly

Tags: javascript

So I am working on a application using PHP and Jquery where a user would be able to store text using a keyword i.e. Keyword "Br" text "Back bone polished". For this particular section the user would be able input the keyword into a text area press enter and the text would then appear in a second text area. I am using "$" to wrap around the keyword inside the text area as there may be other text inside the text area already. For example: Some text $Keyword$ some more text continue $Keyword2$ etc… I have managed to come up with a RegExp as such:

Reg Exp:

```
    match(/[$](.*)[a-zA-Z0-9](.*)[$]/g)
```

Now this works fine when the the text in the text area is structured as follows:

Some text $Keyword$ some more text continue $Keyword2$

However if I were to change the structure to something like this:

$$Some text $Keyword$ some more text continue $Keyword2$ some more text continue $Keyword3,Keyword4 $

It pulls in the entire line instead of just the keywords. What I would like to do is only pull in the text in-between "$"even if there is no text in between the two $$. so for the example the match RegEx should pull in:

1. (blank) because there is nothing in-between the $
2. Keyword
3. Keyword2
4. Keyword3,Keyword4

I am  noob so please be gentle.

Comment: Quick guess: use lazy zero-or-more selection like `(.*?)` Also does the first example ("this works fine") really work? I'm seeing just a complete match from the first `$` to the end of the string. When I change both `.*` to `.*?`, then I get two matches, `["$Keyword$", "$Keyword2$"]`.

Comment: I tried that and there was no change. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your regex as posted means, "match a literal `$`, followed by zero or more arbitrary characters, followed by a single letter or digit, followed by zero or more arbitrary characters, followed by a literal `$`". So, `$;;***,,,,,,FOO(-=+**((()$` would match. Is that the intention?

Comment: I am not really sure I understand what you are saying. I would like to match everything in between the two $

Comment: @apsillers Yes you are correct i get the two matches but I should be getting 4 matches as it isn't pulling in the first group $$ and the last Keyword3,Keyword4

Comment: To be logical and consistent, the last two keywords should be each wrapped in dollar signs for them to get replaced: `$Keyword3$, $Keyword4$`

Comment: Yes you are correct. Once I have all the matches I process them and the output looks like what you have suggested. My issue was it was pulling I'm the wrong info. @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't allow arbitrary characters between the surrounding '$' symbols and the keyword identifier. Change your regex to

```
match(/\$[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]*\$/g)
```

and it should recognize the keywords.

See https://jsfiddle.net/317dgwq5/1/

Comment: When I change the RegExp to what you have suggested I only get two matches instead of 4 as it should be pulling in the first $$ group and the last Keyword3,Keyword4.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've added `\s` to allow white space in the keyword as well. See https://jsfiddle.net/317dgwq5/1/ for a working example

Answer (score 1):

I would use this regex: `/\$(\w+)\$/g`, and make use of the callback function that you can provide to `.replace()`, so that can do the keyword lookup as you match the keywords.

Here is a demo. Just type and the replacement text is immediately displayed through the `oninput` event handler:

```js
var keywords = {
    Keyword: 'about nothing',
    Keyword2: 'reading',
    Keyword3: 'Hello',
    Keyword4: 'Bye',
};

// I/O

var inp = document.getElementById('inp');
var out = document.getElementById('out');

inp.oninput = function() {
    out.value = inp.value.replace(/\$(\w+)\$/g, function(match, key) {
        return keywords[key] || '';
    });
}
inp.oninput();
```

```html
<small>$Keyword$ = about nothing; $Keyword2$ = reading; 
$Keyword3$ = Hello; $Keyword4$ = Bye<br></small>

<textarea id="inp" rows=4 cols=50>$$Some text $Keyword$ some more text continue $Keyword2$ some more text continue $Keyword3,Keyword4 $</textarea>

<textarea id="out" rows=4 cols=50></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

try /\$[a-z0-9]+\$/gim

```js
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify("sadasdjak $aadas$ $$$$ $bbbb$$ccccc$".match(/\$[a-z0-9]+\$/gim))
```